# Rotating Text Using Javascript From Mysql Database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to rotate text in cells of a table every 5 seconds. but i need to get the data from a mysql database. this is the current code that i have which uses a html marquee. (code is in php).

```
echo "<marquee behavior=\Slide\" scrollamount=\"3\" direction=\"left\"height=\"100px\">";  
echo "<a href=\"".$root."Index.php?page=diary\"><table><tr><td ><h2>--Upcoming Events--</h2></td></tr></table></a>";
echo "<table width=\"50px\"><tr><td></td></tr></table>";
for($count = 0; $count < $num_rows; $count++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<a href=\"".$root."Index.php?page=diary\"><table class=\"footer-inner\"><tr><td><p2>Event: ".$row['Title']."</p2></td><td width=\"10px\"></td>";
    echo "<td><p2>Date: ".$row['Date']."</p2></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr> <td><p2>Start Time: ".$row['Start Time']."</p2></td><td width=\"10px\"></td>";
    echo "<td rowspan=\"3\"><p2>Details: ".$row['Text']."</p2></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><p2>End Time: ".$row['End Time']."</p2></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><p2>Location: ".$row['Location']."</p2></td></tr></table></a>";
    echo "<table width=\"50px\"><tr><td></td></tr></table>";
}
echo "</marquee>";
```

I have been doing some research on this and i have found how to rotate the text every x seconds, code for this below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Rotating Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotatingTextElement;
var rotatingText = new Array();
var ctr = 0;

function initRotateText() {
rotatingTextElement = document.getElementById("textToChange");
rotatingText[0] = rotatingTextElement.innerHTML; // store the content that's already on the page
rotatingText[1] = "Ten Reason to Buy Gumballs";
rotatingText[2] = "White House bla bla";
setInterval(rotateText, 5000);
}
function rotateText() {
ctr++;
if(ctr >= rotatingText.length) {
ctr = 0;
}
rotatingTextElement.innerHTML = rotatingText[ctr];
}
window.onload = initRotateText;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="textToChange">New Release... Leopard</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But as you can see this does one line, yes i could do it for every value in a table and i am comfortable with this. But how do i get what i want from the mysql database and insert it into the arrays?

I use php for the page and i can get all the information i need using php, just need to change it to the java script format.

-----EDIT-----

Would it be possible to convert a php array to a javascript array in the same piece of code?

e.g.

```
var rotatingText = Arrayfuction('{php tag} echo $phparray; {php tag}');
```

Comment: Wow! `marquee`? Mmm... `mysql`?

Comment: You should just list out the text you want in separate divs, and then use a javascript library like jQuery to rotate through them every few seconds.

Comment: and how would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJk8Q/3/

I think your php code would be similar to this:

```
for($count = 0; $count < $num_rows; $count++)
{
    texts.push( ".$row['Text'].");  
}
```